# dictionary in django python

Tags: django, django-views, python

In the follwoing code Maps.objects.all() returns all the objects in the tables and get description will return two variables namely name,description.

Now my question i am constructing a dicetionary.If the name is not in the dictionary then i should add it.How this should be done.

**EDIT**
   This needs to be done on python2.4

```
  labels = {}
  maps Maps.objects.all()
  for lm in maps:
     (name,description) = getDescription(lm.name,lm.type)
     if name not in labels:
        labels.update({name,description})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to assign a value to a key in a dictionary if it doesn't exist. Here's a helpful page for [dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Now, to address your question, this should do what you want:

```
labels = {}
maps = Maps.objects.all()
for lm in maps:
    name, description = getDescription(lm.name, lm.type)
    if name not in labels:
        labels[name] = description
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use defaultdict

http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html

```
import collections

labels = collections.defaultdict(list)
maps = Maps.objects.all()
for lm in maps:
    name, description = getDescription(lm.name, lm.type)
    labels[name].append(description)
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to do this in a single line:

```
labels = dict(Maps.objects.values_list('name', 'description'))
```